# Filter h1 HTML With BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm Writing a **CODE Algorithm BELOW**:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import requests
import time
browser =webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:/path/geckodriver.exe')
browser.get('https://brainly.com.br/app/ask?entry=hero&q=15+12')
WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'a[href*="/tarefa"]')))
html=browser.page_source
#html = browser.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")
p=[]
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
for link in soup.select('div.sg-actions-list__hole > a[href*="/tarefa"]'):
    ref=link.get('href')
    rt = ('https://brainly.com.br'+str(ref))
    p.append(rt)

g=[]
for url in p:
    r = requests.get(url).text
    time.sleep(10)


rs= BeautifulSoup(r,'html.parser')


df = rs.select('div > h1')
print(df)
```

`HTML` I need to filter:

```
<div class="brn-content-image">
<h1 class="sg-text sg-text--large sg-text--regular">
Tinha 12 cruzeiros e gastei 15 cruzeiros esta situação pode ser representada por a 15 - 12 B 12 + 15 C 12 - 11 e D - 12 + 15
</h1>
</div>
```

**AND**

```
<div class="brn-content-image">
<h1 class="sg-text sg-text--large sg-text--regular">
[(-15)12]12:(-15)142?
</h1>
</div>
```

At Variable `r` I am storing the source code for 8 URLS, ie 8 Source Code which I am not sure is the problem that I cannot filter it with.

Using Code to Filter HTML:

```
rs= BeautifulSoup(r,'html.parser')
df = rs.select('div > h1')
print(df)
```

**What mistake am I making?.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `Selenium`, you can call the `API` directly which is rendering the `JavaScript` using `XHR` request.

```
import requests

data = [{"operationName": "SearchQuery", "variables": {"query": "15 12", "after": None, "first": 10},
         "query": "query SearchQuery($query: String!, $first: Int!, $after: ID) {\n  questionSearch(query: $query, first: $first, after: $after) {\n    count\n    edges {\n      node {\n        id\n        databaseId\n        author {\n          id\n          databaseId\n          isDeleted\n          nick\n          avatar {\n            thumbnailUrl\n            __typename\n          }\n          rank {\n            name\n            __typename\n          }\n          __typename\n        }\n        content\n        answers {\n          nodes {\n            thanksCount\n            ratesCount\n            rating\n            __typename\n          }\n          hasVerified\n          __typename\n        }\n        __typename\n      }\n      highlight {\n        contentFragments\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n"}]
r = requests.post("https://brainly.com.br/graphql/pt", json=data).json()


for item in r[0]['data']['questionSearch']['edges']:
    print(item['node']['content'])
```

Output:

```
tinha 12 reais e gastei 15 reais essa situaτπo pode ser representada por 15-12   12+15   12-15  -12+15
tinha 12 reais e gastei 15 reais,essa situaτπo pode ser representada por:                                                a)15-12 b)12+15 c)12-15 d)12+15
tinha 12 reais e gastei 15 reais. esta situaτπo pode ser representada por:<br />
a) 15 - 12<br />
b) 12 - 15<br />
c) 12 + 15<br />
d) - 12 + 15
[(-15)12]12:(-15)142?
Tinha r$ 15 e gastei r$ 12 essa situaτπo pode ser representada por .<br />
A)+15 - 12<br />
B) +12 + 15<br />
C + 12 - 15<br />
D -12+15<br />
Me ajude a para amanhπ obrigado <br />
Tinha 12 cruzeiros e gastei 15 cruzeiros esta situaτπo pode ser representada por a 15 - 12 B 12 + 15 C 12 - 11 e D - 12 + 15
Complete as lacunas com um n·mero inteiro, de modo que as igualdades sejam verdadeiras. a) -15 + ___ = 12. <br />
b) 15 + __ = 12. <br />
c) -15 + __ = -12. <br />
d) 15 + ___ = -12
Mediana de 10-10-11-12-12-12-12-12-13-13-13-15-15-15-15-16-16-18-20-20 ? 
 á á á á á á á áA Figura Abaixo representa um terreno com suas dimens⌡es:15+15+12+12+12+12
15 14 12 13 14 14 15 10 10 12 13 10 15 10 12 12 12 14 15 12 Determine a Moda Dessa distribuiτπo de frequΩncia?
```

> Update for `links`:

```py
for item in r[0]['data']['questionSearch']['edges']:
    print(f"https://brainly.com.br/tarefa/{item['node']['databaseId']}")
```

Output:

```
https://brainly.com.br/tarefa/4726592
https://brainly.com.br/tarefa/2645408
https://brainly.com.br/tarefa/1610749
https://brainly.com.br/tarefa/6008293
https://brainly.com.br/tarefa/13872231
https://brainly.com.br/tarefa/22541768
https://brainly.com.br/tarefa/4531702
https://brainly.com.br/tarefa/23553975
https://brainly.com.br/tarefa/7061395
https://brainly.com.br/tarefa/13037193
```

Comment: Have How to Explain, or Do Something Using BeautifulSoup.

Comment: @Soares you do have a Python dictionary right now ! which you can access any items you want from it ! instead of using selenium

Comment: It would be nice to use this for saving processing, but also need to get the links from the homepage that would not be possible with this api can tell me Link: https://brainly.com.br/app/ask?entry=hero&q=15+12

what and redirecting tasks

Comment: @Soares which links you want? give me example ?

Comment: I need the links that lead to the tasks

Comment: Ours Is Perfect, The Solution Is Not Within the Title With BeautifulSoup
but this solution would make it much easier that I want to do what I recommend to read about it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205620/discussion-between--c-and-soares).

Answer (score 1):

Try with this :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div class="brn-content-image">
<h1 class="sg-text sg-text--large sg-text--regular">
Tinha 12 cruzeiros e gastei 15 cruzeiros esta situação pode ser representada por a 15 - 12 B 12 + 15 C 12 - 11 e D - 12 + 15
</h1>
</div>
<div class="brn-content-image">
<h1 class="sg-text sg-text--large sg-text--regular">
[(-15)12]12:(-15)142?
</h1>
</div> 
       """
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

for n in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'brn-content-image'}):    
   print(n.find('h1').text)
```

Comment: Is it possible for me to replace the html variable with the r where the html is already?

Comment: I generate an error:
 BeautifulSoup ([your markup], "lxml")

  markup_type = markup_type))

Comment: I added 'html.parser'

Comment: And not how to do a cleaner filtering, just like to make what's inside the h1 tag.

Comment: I added .text in print(n.find('h1')

Comment: I tested the code and it only prints only 1 resulting.

Comment: Looks Like Mentioning Above I am saving 8 source code from different pages in a single variable and I believe that is the problem as only 1 item from h1 is printed.

Comment: and if you try with another for :  for x in n.find_all('h1')